# Python variable is not being initialized

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I have the following AWS Lambda function in Python:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Code
    # ..
    # ..
    # ..
    # Code

    output = ' '

    for key in diff.keys():
        for value in diff[key]:
            output += "<br> Key: " + key + ", Value: " + value + "</br>"

    print output
```

Each time i run the function, The value of `output` is being appended to the value of the previous running, Although it's being initialized with `output = ' '`.

For example, If the value of `output` is:

```
<br> Key: " + A + ", Value: " + 1 + "</br>
<br> Key: " + B + ", Value: " + 2 + "</br>
```

On the next running the value will be:

```
<br> Key: " + A + ", Value: " + 1 + "</br>
<br> Key: " + A + ", Value: " + 1 + "</br>
<br> Key: " + B + ", Value: " + 2 + "</br>
<br> Key: " + B + ", Value: " + 2 + "</br>
```

And on the next running it will be:

```
<br> Key: " + A + ", Value: " + 1 + "</br>
<br> Key: " + A + ", Value: " + 1 + "</br>
<br> Key: " + A + ", Value: " + 1 + "</br>
<br> Key: " + B + ", Value: " + 2 + "</br>
<br> Key: " + B + ", Value: " + 2 + "</br>
<br> Key: " + B + ", Value: " + 2 + "</br>
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: the error is in the code before the for-loop. `diff` is not initialized correctly.

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue. `diff` was initialized at the wrong place. Now it works great.